# What "label" stand for in scikit learn documentation in the metric for clusering?

Tags: python, algorithm, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have texts that I'm trying to clusterize:

```
# Training
hasher = HashingVectorizer(non_negative=True,norm="l1", analyzer="char", ngram_range=(5,9))
vectorizer = make_pipeline(hasher, TfidfTransformer())
training = vectorizer.fit_transform(list_of_texts)

#LSA
svd = TruncatedSVD(100)
lsa = make_pipeline(svd, Normalizer(copy=False))
training = lsa.fit_transform(training)

# Clustering
km = KMeans(n_clusters=8, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=3)
km.fit(training)
```

After this steps I want to see how well or bad my clusters are. I found those metrics:

```
metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels_pred))
metrics.completeness_score(labels_true, labels_pred))
metrics.v_measure_score(labels_true, labels_pred))
metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels_pred))
```

I guess `labels_pred` stand for the label given by the clustering algorithm. But I can't find out what the `labels_true` stand for, the documentation state:

> ground truth class labels to be used as a reference

But I don't have labels. Other way I would apply a classification algorithm and not a clustering algorithm.

What should be those `labels_true`? How can I evaluate my cluster without those label?

Comment: labels_pred should be your predictions, the outcome of your estimators. labels_true are the actual values. You need both to compare how well/close your predictions are to the actual situation (in your case).

Comment: But I don't have "actual values", other way it will be a classification problem

Comment: All the above you mentioned have the [drawback that they require ground truth](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#drawbacks). Use [silhouette coefficient](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#silhouette-coefficient) instead.

Comment: @VivekKumar Ok thanks can you make an answer?

Comment: This question is not suitable for StackOverflow, in my opinion. Thats why I only commented about it. I only suggested a single metric. Trying it on [Cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) may give you better insights about the metrics.

Comment: My question is about programmation AND can be answered so it fulfil all the conditions of stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Thats why I said its my opinion. And you have asked this like "How can I evaluate my cluster without those label?" From this sentence, this looks like more suitable for cross-validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External evaluation measures *two* classifications. One is assumed to be a known good classification, the other the output of your clustering. This kind of measures can be seen as a *similarity function* for clusterings.

This is only applicable if you have a so called "ground truth", which may apply in an academic setting, but will usually not hold in real use.

The alternative is to use *internal* measures like Silhouette. But in my experience they only work for low-dimensional data either. On text, I have yet to see a high Silhouette. Also, Silhouette takes O(n²) to compute, so it doesn't work on large data sets at all.